# check if a column exists before altering the table

Tags: sql, sqlite

How would I execute such a query? Here's an example query that adds a new column.

```
ALTER TABLE [users] ADD COLUMN [description] VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
```

Whenever that query is executed again, it produces the following error.

> SQLiteManager: Likely SQL syntax error: ALTER TABLE [users] ADD
>   COLUMN [description] VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' [ duplicate
>   column name: description ] Exception Name: NS_ERROR_FAILURE Exception
>   Message: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005
>   (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [mozIStorageConnection.createStatement]

I'd like to eliminate that error if possible. For example, the following query doesn't produce any errors when executed multiple times.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [users] ([id_users] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT)
```

But SQLite doesn't support IF condition at the beginning of a query, so I'm pretty much clueless as what to do. I've also tried using CASE expression, but failed. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to do this with a single `ALTER TABLE` statement.

You could check if the column exists with another command (like [`PRAGMA table_info(users)`](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_table_info)).

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'll accept this since no one else has replied.